# Insertar datos en dos tablas diferentes con MVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc, insert

Tengo dos tablas que se relacionan, una de ellas depende de la información de la 1ra tabla (pagos depende de contratos). Solo debo ocupar un formulario para guardar de la información.

Así tengo la función del registro en el Controlador:

```
public function registro_contrato()
{
    $id_client = $this->Clientes_model->lastID_Cliente();
    $clienteid = ($id_client[0]->id_cliente);

    $id_dom_instalacion = $this->Clientes_model->lastID_Domicilio();
    //Omicion de datos para facil lectura....
    $tres_pago       = $this->input->post("tres_pago");

    //Datos a guardar en la otra tabla 
    $costo_instalacion   = $this->input->post("costo_instalacion");
    $monto_anticipo      = $this->input->post("monto_anticipo");
    $forma_de_pago       = $this->input->post("forma_de_pago");
    $restante            = $this->input->post("restante");
    $tres_pagos          = $this->input->post("tres_pagos");

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $data = array(
            'fecha_de_contrato'               => $fecha_de_contrato,
            //Omicion de datos para facil lectura....
            'tres_pago'                   => $tres_pago,

            //Datos a guardar en la otra tabla 
            'costo_instalacion'               => $costo_instalacion,
            'monto_anticipo'                  => $monto_anticipo,
            'forma_de_pago'                   => $forma_de_pago,
            'restante'                        => $restante,
            'tres_pagos'                      => $tres_pagos,
        );

        if ($this->Clientes_model->save_contrato($data)) {

            redirect(base_url() . "clientes/clientes_controller");

        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "No se pudo guardar la informacion"); 
            redirect(base_url() . "clientes/clientes_controller/agregar_contrato");
        }
    } else {
        $this->agregar_contrato();
    }
}
```

La función en el Modelo:

```
public function save_contrato($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert("contratos", $data);
}
```

Actualmente funciona perfecto para el guardado en la tabla "Contratos" pero no tengo ni idea de como implementar el guardado de los últimos 5 registros (y el id como llave primaria) en la tabla "Pagos".
Agradecería una ayuda con ello... Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo tienes (mas o menos).

Tendrías que modificar la función `save_contrato` para que quedase con algo como:

```
public function save_contrato($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert('pagos', $data) && $this->db->insert('contratos', $data);
}
```

Eso confío en que te dará una idea de por donde seguir. Pero ten en cuenta que puede ser necesaria mas lógica según como quieras hacer inserciones en la tabla `pagos`, ejemplo: si la `id` relacionada en la tabla `pagos` no existe deberás crearla previamente (hacer las inserciones en `pagos`, anotar que `id` se han generado y actuar en consecuencia sobre `contratos`). O si necesitas hacer inserciones múltiples (5 registros, como mencionas).

Sería, entonces, mas fácil de mantener separadas las inserciones en funciones distintas, algo como:

```
public function save_contrato($data)
{
    return save_pagos($data) && $this->db->insert('contratos', $data);
}

public function save_pagos($data)
{
    //lógica para inserción múltiple, filtrado de datos, etc.
    return $this->db->insert('contratos', $data);
}
```

Comment: Mas o menos estaba siguiendo la segunda forma antes de verla (Valla, si llegue a una idea casi igual pero distinta) y recordando que no pasare todo el $data (ya que este consta de 20 registros) si no solo el 1er registro y los últimos 5 registros de la tabla "Contratos" a "Pagos". Ahora mismo lo que me detiene es un error que (supuestamente) seria relacionado a la forma de inserción con SET. Al menos creo que por ahí va el rumbo aunque no estoy muy seguro debido a mi poca experiencia con el campo de la programacion.